# We have more than 1,200 unresolved [story-identification] questions >3 months old. Is that a problem?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

[This search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+score%3A1..+closed%3Ano+%5Bstory-identification%5D+lastactive%3A..3m) returns [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions that are:

- Positively scored.
- Completely unanswered.  Downvoted and zero-score unaccepted answers *do* count, unlike the "unanswered" tab.
- Not (currently) closed.
- Most recently active (asked, edited) three or more months ago.  Comments don't count.

At the time of writing (2017-10-08 in America/Los_Angeles, the next day in UTC) there are 1,274 results.  If we [remove the date restriction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+score%3A1..+closed%3Ano+%5Bstory-identification%5D), we get 1,501 results, which means that **almost 85% of all unanswered, open, upvoted story ID questions haven't been touched in three months**.  While [old story ID questions do get answers from time to time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2937/36526), I think it's spectacularly unlikely that we can clear this backlog faster than it is accumulating (which was [quite fast](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7509/36526) the last time we discussed this), so that percentage is likely to rise over time.

- Is this the right question to ask of the data?  In other words, should we care about the boldfaced statement above?
- If so, what should we do about it?

Answer (score 19):

**No, we should not care.**

There's no real limit to the number of unresolved questions we can keep lying around.  These are not bad questions, and their presence does not harm the site.  If we do the [same search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+score%3A1..+closed%3Ano+%5Bjava%5D+lastactive%3A..3m) on Stack Overflow with the popular [java] tag, and [again without the date range](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+score%3A1..+closed%3Ano+%5Bjava%5D), we can see that their ratio has gotten all the way up to 94%, and obviously the sky has not fallen.

Comment: Looks like you've resolved your own issue ;-)

Comment: Yeah I don't see why we should care. Some questions are just really hard to answer, even with sufficient details. Also these questions are a good way for new users to get some rep if they happen to know the answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Yeah, when I first saw those numbers I got a bit freaked, but a little more digging shows it's probably no big deal.

Comment: @Zabeus - Plus it's always nice to have a dig around in the pile to see if there's anything that looks familiar. A lot of old, established unsolved questions have been solved by users using new tools, new knowledge and plain old-fashioned legwork to resolve them

Comment: {nods} I just answered two of them (one of which was, admittedly, a case of the answer being provided in the comments and even accepted by the querent there).

Comment: @zabeus Did you see the [tetris in GOL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life) on PPCG ever? It took *years* of hard work to solve.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere They got rushed near the end because somebody posted a bounty on the question instead of using the "future bounty-for-impossible-questions" meta post.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yeah, I know. But it was still a tremendus effort.