# I asked a dumb question, now what do I do about it?

Tags: discussion

A couple of days ago, I was wondering about an apparent redundancy in the closing words of General Hux's speech in Star Wars: The Force Awakens.  What I should have done was sit on the question for a couple of days and figure out how to ask it, but I posted it right away as ["Was General Hux's Speech Ad-libbed?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146842/was-general-huxs-speech-ad-libbed)  What I meant to ask (20/20 hindsight) was more along the lines of how rigorously he rehearsed his speech, but as it stands right now it's a pretty lame question, totally deserving of the downvotes it received.

So what should I do?  Is there a way to admit, "OK, I asked a bad question, please don't downvote it any more than it already is"?  Should I edit the question?  Or should I just let it fade into the background?

Comment: Assuming you typed that block quote by hand verbatim while listening to the movie, the only reason it's a bad question is lack of research (which for some reason isn't a close reason on SFF) where you could have just looked up and compared it to [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) (which I'm assuming wasn't transcribed and is an actual shooting script - now *that* would be a valid question).

Comment: Just don’t ever. Do. It. Again.

Comment: @Mazura About the GR close reason: [Should we burninate General Reference?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2400/21267)

Comment: @Mooz - If I went around DVing because I think something is GR, I'd have to DV almost everything. I'm used to ELU's close reason: "Please **include the research** you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic." It's more polite than saying LMGTFY. You can ask 'GR' questions, IMO, so long as you include at least two (ideally, front page) contradicting sources.

Comment: People pointing out the error are providing information for those of us who didn't know it was an error; so I consider it valuable.

Answer (score 10):

If you think you can edit it into a good question, do that<sup>1</sup>. ***Always*** do that. Otherwise:

### Learn from your mistakes and let it be

There's really nothing else you *can* do:

- Asking people not to downvote is likely to have negligible effect; if anything it may *encourage* downvotes, because this is the Internet and sometimes people are horrible
- You can't delete the question, [because](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/276025) it has an upvoted answer. Unless you can convince Valorum to delete his answer (or convince a moderator to delete the question, which seems even less likely), there's nothing else to be done about it

Eventually, people will stop caring about this question; it's already [demonstrably true](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7619/31051) that older questions get less attention, and we can see that looking at the [timeline for your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/146842/timeline): it got 4 downvotes yesterday, but only 1 today; it may get a couple more votes today, because of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/276025), but I suspect by the end of the week you'll stop hearing much from it. It also doesn't hurt that questions with a -5 score (which your question doesn't have, but isn't far from) are hidden from the front page.

Everybody makes mistakes. What matters is that you learn from them.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just be careful not to radically change the context of the question, or modify it in such a way that existing answers are invalid. Both of those are frowned upon by the community

Comment: Great minds think alike? :-)

Comment: @Jason what do you think of the question now?

Answer (score 6):

- You could **edit it** and hope that people notice and reverse their votes. (Don't get your hopes up too high though - a lot of people who vote on a question never come back to it after that. The more likely possibility would be to get enough upvotes to counter the downvotes it's already had.)
- Alternatively, you could just **leave it**. We've all asked bad questions at one point or another. Your [question-asking history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/73743/bob?tab=questions) is good enough that you're not going to get question-blocked just because of this. Nobody will hold it against you.

There are also a few things you *shouldn't* do.

- Don't edit in a note to say "please don't downvote this any further". Such notices tend to act as downvote magnets in practice.
- Don't delete the question. You can't, because it has an upvoted answer.
- Don't edit it so as to completely change its meaning and invalidate the existing answer. If you want to ask something entirely different, post a new question instead.

Comment: I rewrote the question—how does it look now?